# Create a calculations operator in python

Tags: python, vector, operators

So I am developing a class for vectorial calculations, and I overwrote the `__mul__(self, b)` function to do a Scalarproduct. Now whenever I write `A * B` it calculates as I want it to. So I would like to do the same with an `x` for the Crossproduct. Sadly there is no default `x` operator in python, it would probably just annoy you. But is there a way to create your own operator which ONLY works for my own class, but can otherwise be used in a code aswell (as a variable definition I mean)? Or maybe define `***` as an operator?

Comment: In brief: No, you cannot define your own operators in Python.

Comment: As DYZ's pointer question suggests, you may want to check out this hacky approach: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/384122-infix-operators/

Comment: In recent versions of Python you could override [the `__matmul__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__matmul__), which is associated with the `@` operator. It's _supposed_ to be for matrix multiplication, but that's not a hard & fast rule.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just define an operator, you can write your own interpreter for your own language inside python. Basically, you need to create 4 modules

- parser
- environment
- eval
- repl

Then you can program with your own language within python.

read [Peter Novig's article](http://norvig.com/lispy.html) for a detailed example of a python LISP interpreter